# Authentication (AWS Cognito) for an microservice architecture with an angular frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am in the process of building an microservice architecture with an angular frontend as ui component. Each microservice uses flask-restx and pycognito to secure its routes. The frontend uses aws-amplify to authenticate users. Each microservice expects a valid token for the secured routes, which is validated in the respective backend. In the aws user pool we created multiple app clients. The goal is to authenticate once against the webapp and use the token to access all microservice backend. I already tried to find the correct solution in the aws documentation but had no luck until now. Maybe somebody could give me a hint what is the best practice solution to get this done right.

Comment: Why do u need multiple app clients at cognito. each backend needs each app client. r8?

Comment: Currently we actually use the same app client for the web frontend and our test microservice. And so we can authenticate on the frontend and the token is also valid in the backend (microservice).  This is also the reason why I am asking what would be the right approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and stupid (KISS).
I cannot see any use-case of multiple app clients.

Please follow the steps below at microservices end:

1. Cognito uses asymmetric keys to generate jwt token.
2. So, get the public key from Cognito by this code [link](https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt/blob/master/src/django_cognito_jwt/validator.py#L56).
3. Decode that jwt token by public key [link](https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt/blob/master/src/django_cognito_jwt/validator.py#L61).
4. Authentication will be done by above step. if invalid token is passed in request header `jwt.decode` function will raise exception [link](https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt/blob/master/src/django_cognito_jwt/validator.py#L61).
5. Decoded payload contains `sub` and store that sub in distributed db (dynamodb, SQL)
6. One can store custom attributes and assign Cognito user to group. This will help to authorize the individual users on the microservice side.

I hope that gives you a hint to go ahead.

Comment: As long as we use the same app client id for the microservice and the web frontend this works exactly as you described (encapsulated by pycognito). So, we would end up using the same app client id for all microservices without a secret key (not allowed for the web frontend)? How do you think a secure communication could be then implemented directly between the various microservices without the secret key?

Comment: Ah. I skipped machine to machine (M2M) communication.